# C++ returning object created on heap and modifying it, doesnt change it?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14, memory-address

I have following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    struct bar {
        int foobar;
    };

    vector<bar*> barp;

    bar & insert(int v){
        bar * b = new bar();
        (*b).foobar = v;
        barp.push_back(b);
        return *b;
    }

    void edit(bar & b, int v){
        b.foobar = v;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    foo::bar b = f.insert(5);
    f.edit(b, 10);
    std::cout << (b.foobar == 10?"true":"false") << std::endl;//now ok
    std::cout << (b.foobar == 5?"true":"false") << std::endl;//now ok
    std::cout << ((*f.barp[0]).foobar == 10?"true":"false") << std::endl;//after edit, still returns false
    std::cout << ((*f.barp[0]).foobar == 5?"true":"false") << std::endl;//after edit, returns true
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain me, why doesnt the "b.foobar" change to 10? Doesnt the b have the same address as the one saved in f.barp[0]?

EDIT:Thanks for answers, adding reference to void edit(bar & b, int v) does, of course, make sense. However adding reference to "bar & insert" doesnt seem to change anything, as the (*f.barp[0]).foobar stays unchanged after edit, even though insert should return reference now.

Comment: What do you believe `return *b` does?

Comment: The object, to whose pointer is saved in f.barp, no?

Comment: `SuhDude555` `b` is not the same object as the one whose address is stored in `barp`. Imagine it with any other type: `int insert(int v){int *b=new int(); *b = v; barp.push_back(b); return *b;}`

Answer (score 3):

> Doesn't the `b` have the same address as the one saved in `f.barp[0]`?

No, it does not. You return the object by value from the insert, i.e.

```
bar insert(int v)
^^^
```

Returning by value implies a copy: a new `bar` is constructed using a copy constructor, and the original one is discarded<sup>*</sup>.

To get the results that you expect, return `bar&` from `insert`:

```
bar& insert(int v) {
// ^
}
```

Similarly, `edit` should take its parameter by reference if you would like all functions to work on the same object.

<sup>*</sup> If it were not for you storing the pointer in a collection, this would also create a memory leak. Your program does have memory leak, too, but you can fix it by deleting objects in the `barp` vector.

Comment: `edit` should also take by reference.  I'd suggest `insert` to return a pointer to serve as self-documentation that the lifetime of the referred-to object needs to be considered

Comment: There _is_ a memory leak in the given program.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet That's true, but OP could fix it by iterating the vector of pointers, and deleting them. Without the vector the pointer would be gone for good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to do it without returning pointer on "insert"? Just returning reference or object on "insert" ? Edited my question a bit.

Comment: @SuhDude555 `bar&` indicates returning a reference, not a pointer. `bar*` would be a pointer.

Comment: I'm just saying. Your answer suggests there's no memory leak. Yet, there is a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, and i would like to avoid returning bar*, yet bar& doesnt seem to help, with f.edit(b, 10); (*f.barp[0]).foobar.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're passing the parameter to `edit()` by value, instead of by reference.

`edit()` ends up modifying a copy of the original object, which then immediately gets thrown away.

Also, you are returning a copy of the record from `insert()`, as well.

Your `insert()` must return a pointer, instead of a copy of the new record. You must also pass a pointer to `edit()`, too.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesnt the b have the same address as the one saved in f.barp[0]?

No, it does not.  *Every time* you use `bar` with no further qualifications as an argument or return type, you are asking for a copy to be made.  In this case, that means *both* the variable `b` in `main` and the variable `b` in `edit` are copies.

For this toy example, you can make the program do what you expected with these changes:

```
- bar insert(int v){
+ bar &insert(int v){

- void edit(bar b, int v){
+ void edit(bar &b, int v){

- foo::bar b = f.insert(5);
+ foo::bar &b = f.insert(5);
```

If you do not understand what that does or why, please consult a C++ textbook for an explanation of "references".

(If you've never seen the above `-`/`+` notation before, it means "replace each line marked with a minus sign with the corresponding line marked with a plus sign.")

Comment: Good. It would be clearer if you wrote `bar& insert` instead of `bar &insert` (and similarly elsewhere). Aligning the ampersand right is a key cause of this very misunderstanding with newbies, because `&expr` means "address-of" instead of "reference type".

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I will not do that.  `&` binds to the right in declarations, so it needs to be written the way I wrote it, with the space on the left.  I can see what you mean about `&expr`, but I consider the potential confusion from `bar& a, b;` not doing what it looks like it does to be *much worse*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i edited my question a bit, could you look at it now? Sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: @zwol: What, that one, single, remote, unusual edge case? Is "much worse" than literally every other usage, plus the confusion over multiple meanings of `&`? Sorry, I spectacularly disagree, with evidence on SO daily. http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/ _"It needs to be written the way I wrote it"_ Simply wrong. No it doesn't "need" to be written any such way. And certainly not for implementation reasons!!

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet If you think that's an unusual edge case you are a fortunate soul.

Comment: @SuhDude555 You need to make all three of the changes I showed, not just two of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo::bar b = f.insert(5);
```

This b object is different from *f.barp[0] since it is *created* from returned reference. 
To make this work, change this line to

```
foo::bar& b = f.insert(5);
```

That way you are creating a reference to the object which you just inserted in the vector.